# Why web services in .NET use XML Serializer rather then SOAP Serializer?

Tags: .net, web-services

I am new with web services and I cannot find answer why web services in .NET use XML serialization in order to generate SOAP message rather then use SOAP serialization and benefit from it i.e. to be able to serialize object graph and private class members.

Comment: The "web services" you're talking about appear to be the ASMX web services which are a legacy technology. You should be using WCF for new web service development.

Answer (score -3):

xml serialization is cross platform,it means its platform independent so it can be once serialized then use it at anywhere in the form of webservice ,because the web service returns us xml dataset so further we can incorporate this resultset to everywhere as independently